# SpringBoot test - Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2, activiti

I have this class in my springBoot app:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ ApplicationTestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    private HistoryService historyService;
..
}
```

my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

my pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.200</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

but when I run the test I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this if it may work for you

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
<artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```